# audio is shown disable in twilio video chat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I am trying to create a video chat with twilio. I could turn the webcam and run the video, however i could not make the audio work. When i select the control, i get to enlarge the video and picture to picture mode but not control the audio.

This is how seen

[image]

Here is the code

```
function App() {
  let localMediaRef = React.useRef(null);;
  const [data, setIdentity] = React.useState({
    identity: null,
    token: null
  });
  const [room, setRoom] = React.useState({
    activeRoom: null,
    localMediaAvailable: null,
    hasJoinedRoom: null
  });
  async function fetchToken() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/token");
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      const { identity, token } = jsonResponse;
      setIdentity({
          identity,
          token
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("e", e);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchToken();
  }, []);

  const attachTracks = (tracks, container) => {
    tracks.forEach(track => {
      container.appendChild(track.attach());
    });
  };

  // Attaches a track to a specified DOM container
  const attachParticipantTracks = (participant, container) => {
    const tracks = Array.from(participant.tracks.values());
    attachTracks(tracks, container);
  };

  const roomJoined = room => {
    // Called when a participant joins a room
    console.log("Joined as '" + data.identity + "'");
    setRoom({
      activeRoom: room,
      localMediaAvailable: true,
      hasJoinedRoom: true
    });

    // Attach LocalParticipant's Tracks, if not already attached.
    const previewContainer = localMediaRef.current;
    if (!previewContainer.querySelector("video")) {
      attachParticipantTracks(room.localParticipant, previewContainer);
    }
  };

  const joinRoom = () => {
    let connectOptions = {
      name: "Interview Testing"
    };
    let settings = {
      audio: true
    }
    console.log('data', data, data.token)
    Video.connect(
      data.token,
      connectOptions,
      settings
    ).then(roomJoined, error => {
      alert("Could not connect to Twilio: " + error.message);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <FeatureGrid>
          <span onClick={joinRoom}>Webcam</span>
        </FeatureGrid>
        <PanelGrid>
          {room.localMediaAvailable ? (
            <VideoPanels>
              <VideoPanel ref={localMediaRef} />
            </VideoPanels>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </PanelGrid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How do i enable audio too? Also the settings of video is shown only after right click. can't we show this by default?

UPDATE

its a LocalAudioTrack

[image]

this is remoteaudiotrack

[image]

Comment: Have you rejected the browser permission for audio? Are you running the app on localhost or HTTPS? Are you able to get audio from your microphone using `getUserMedia`? Is that for the local or remote stream (you don't want to hear your local stream as that will just cause feedback)?

Comment: Nup, i have not rejected the permission. I am running the app on localhost. I did not try getUserMedia.

Comment: Is it the local or remote stream that you are looking at there?

Comment: I am looking for remote stream.

Comment: @philnash can you help me at this, in any way? I mean either local or remote.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what it might be. When you are `attach`ing the tracks you do so individually. The video is just the video track hence no audio control. Is there an `<audio>` element too? Also, I would start by logging the tracks that you are receiving from the remote stream to see if there is an audio one available.

Comment: how do i do that? I am sorry this is the very first time I am using twilio.

Comment: In your `attachTracks` method call `console.log(tracks)` and inspect them to see whether there is an audio track.

Comment: i have attached screenshot in the question. There is an audio track(LocalAudioTrack)

Comment: OK, but as I described above, the local audio track isn't played back to you as that would just cause feedback. What do you get for the remote participant?

Comment: updated with remoteparticipant as well. I cant control audio settings.

Comment: The screenshot you've shown for the remote participant is a video track (just the visuals). Is there a `RemoteAudioTrack`? If not, the remote participant isn't sending audio and that's why you can't control it.

Comment: sorry i mistakely uploaded video screenshot. I have updated it now. I could listen the sound but i could not control the audio like volume increase, decrease or mute from the controls given by twilio itself.

Comment: In the HTML of the page, next to the `<video>` element, is there an `<audio>` element? And can you make it visible, by adding the `controls` attribute to it?

Comment: There is `<audio autoplay>` element. I added the `controls` attribute and it show up separately just beside the video now but not inside the video as in screenshot

Comment: Cool, so you are getting the audio track and you can control the audio. What's happening here is that the SDK is adding the audio and video tracks to the page separately, so they manifest as separate elements. So you can't control the volume of the audio from the video element, nor can you control playback of the video from the audio element. You can, however, hook into each of these elements and build the controls you want for your application.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am just trying to have volume up and down and mute our webcam audio .

Comment: When you call `element.attach(track)` with the audio track you will be returned an `HTMLAudioElement` which implements the [`HTMLMediaElement` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). You can use the `HTMLAudioElement` to implement muting and volume control for your users.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping nature. I appreciate your help.